# pandoc img attributes in markdown

Tags: image, attributes, markdown, pandoc

I know that the problem seems to be closed about using attributes (like a class) for images in Pandoc's Markdown ([here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/261) or [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/pull/14)), but I cannot get out.

If somebody knows how to do it, I would appreciate much!

Comment: please show your code, its output, and explain how this is not what you expected

Comment: also make sure you're using the newest pandoc version...

Answer (score 1):

As you did not specify exactly, I can only assume that you might wanted to see an example like this?

```
![caption text](path/to/graphic.png){width=50%}
```